# rosrun: unable to locate the node robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros-control, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The exact error I am having is

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_state_publisher/state_publisher]: can't locate node [state_publisher] in package [robot_state_publisher]
```

I have cloned the `robot_state_publisher` from ros wiki and already had done `rosmake`.

I have also sourced the terminal to devel before using `rosrun` aswell as exported all the reqaquired core packages and python path to the terminal before trying to run the `robot_state_publisher`.

here is the my CmakeList.txt file,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(robot_state_publisher)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra")

find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS roscpp rosconsole rostime tf tf2_ros tf2_kdl kdl_parser
)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

find_package(urdfdom_headers REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}_solver
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  DEPENDS roscpp rosconsole rostime tf2_ros tf2_kdl kdl_parser orocos_kdl urdfdom_headers
)

include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${urdfdom_headers_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${orocos_kdl_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_solver
  src/robot_state_publisher.cpp src/treefksolverposfull_recursive.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_solver ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})

add_library(joint_state_listener src/joint_state_listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(joint_state_listener ${PROJECT_NAME}_solver ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/joint_state_listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_solver ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})

# compile the same executable using the old name as well
add_executable(state_publisher src/joint_state_listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(state_publisher ${PROJECT_NAME}_solver ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})
```

Can you please help me solve this problem, I am trying to run a robot I have designed using xacro on gazebo and control it with ros. I have already installed `ros_control` and `ros_gazebo` packages. Thank you advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311957/rosrun:-unable-to-locate-the-node-robot_state_publisher/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:\

> I have cloned the `robot_state_publisher` from ros wiki

why?

> and already had done `rosmake`.

why?

Did `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher` not work for you?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
Please remove `robot_state_publisher` from your workspace (remove your `build` and `devel` folders as well), install the binary version, rebuild your workspace and try again.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-04**:
after cloning it from the wiki, I had used rosmake to compile the cloning package. I am not sure whether its mandatory or not but I followed the same process i follow to create any new packages on catkin workspace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:\

> I followed the same process i follow to create any new packages on catkin workspace.

`rosmake` is not used for Catkin packages. That would be `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
In general: *always* try to use binary packages and install them using `apt` (or `apt-get`). There are few cases where you'd want to / need to build packages from source. `git clone` should not be your default for installing ROS packages.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-04**:
build and devel folders contains other ros packages that I have been using. Doesn't remove the entire folders affect the entire project in a way that I had to create them all again ? and also may I know how it is going to help ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:\

> build and devel folders contains other ros packages that I have been using. Doesn't remove the entire folders affect the entire project in a way that I had to create them all again ?

`build` and `devel` contain only *derived* resources -- if you're using a normal Catkin workspace setup. ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
.. That means that after removing `build` and `devel`, a `catkin_make` should result in all the pkgs in `src` being rebuilt. In the end `devel` should contain the same packages as before.

> and also may I know how it is going to help ?

you've added `robot_state_publisher` to your workspace, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
.. and then built your workspace. If you now remove `src/robot_state_publisher`, but do not rebuild your workspace, your ROS environment will still point to the `robot_state_publisher` in your workspace, even though you've removed it.

That's why a rebuild is a good idea.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-04**:
Thank you very much , I have deleted the devel and build directories from the catkin workspace and when I used catkin_make command as you said they are created again. Thanks for explaining me the part.  So you suggest me to remove the cloned robot_state_publisher and then rebuild my workspace...

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-04**:
..and then install the robot-state-publisher using the apt-get command?  I am kind of beginer to the ROS and catkin environment. so when you suggested me to rebuild, can you please tell me what exactly you meant ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:
To get this clear first: *always* first try to use `apt` (or `apt-get`) to install ROS pkgs. Don't go `git clone`ing things. That's not how this works and it should not be your go-to command when installing ROS pkgs. There are situations where it's needed, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As to your question: yes. Remove `src/robot_state_publisher`, remove `devel` and `build` folders, run `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher` and then rebuild your workspace (run `catkin_make`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-06**:
Thank you very much, now I have got it about how to install. Thank you once again.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-01-07**:
the question I have asked had already been answered although I have got a beginner confusion , could you please point me where  the packages I installed using apt-get command located ? I have checked in the ros folder and it contains only ros core packages. can you please help me ?

**Comment by [sciduck](https://answers.ros.org/users/56604/sciduck/) on 2020-08-19**:
try

```
roscd robot_state_publisher/
```

then

```
pwd
```